# Layers tab not showing

Tags: interface

[image: Blender help]

Usually my layers tab appears in the area of the red circle, but I did something that changed it. I would like to know how to get it back. Thanks!

Comment: You're in local view press Numpad '/'

Answer (score 11):

You pressed the <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> key switching you into [Local View](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Global_or_Local_View). Scene layers and lock buttons do not show there. Press  <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> again to go back into Global view

Comment: some of us use tenkeyless >:(

Comment: For those of us who use a laptop without a Numpad: Object Mode, View, View Global/Local

Comment: thanks, it worked. I got so stressed when all my models just disappered and i didn't even remembered what i pressed.

Comment: Its the `:` key on a german keyboard